# How to start the Appium server from command prompt in MAC machine?

Tags: ios, node.js, appium

I am automating [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) native mobile application using [appium](/questions/tagged/appium). Until now I was launching the server from the Appium GUI by clicking on the Launch button. Now I want to start the server from a command prompt.

I was able to do the same in Windows machine by following the below steps:

1. Launch Node.js command prompt
2. Navigate till the Appium bin folder
3. Use the command `node appium`

I got blocked on how to start the Node.js command prompt on a Mac. Can you pleases tell me how I can start the Appium server from a command prompt on a Mac.

Comment: This question might be better off on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9):

if you used npm install -g appium then you should be able to directly open one with the command

```
appium //plus any server args you want ex: appium -p 4474
```

Or  you can still navigate to the folder of your node_modules and into appium and go with

```
node . //plus any server args you want
```

if you want to have additional server flags, all are available at their site with documentations.

Answer (score 5):

Open the terminal and type in the following command

```
appium --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723
```

Press enter then it will register itself to 127.0.0.1 and will listen 4723 port. You can extend this command by adding app type etc.

Hope this will help you

cheers

Answer (score 3):

```
/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --no-reset --local-timezone --command-timeout 7200 --session-override --debug-log-spacing --platform-version 9.0 --platform-name iOS --app /Users/chennareddy/u/apps/TestApp/build/release-iphonesimulator/Handstand/Handstand.app --show-ios-log --device-name iPhone-6s --native-instruments-lib --orientation Portrait
```

Comment: This works on 1.4.12 and allows capabilities to be passed unlike the methods suggested above

Answer (score 1):

To start appium in MAC, all you need to do is to type => **appium &** in the terminal application. In order for the above command to work, you have to install appium in terminal mode. However there are 2 ways of doing it, one is with HomeBrew and the other directly with Node.js . You can find the tutorial of installing HomeBrew online. Follow the steps below to install it directly with node.js -

1. Go to https://nodejs.org/
2. Download and install the latest stable version of node.js package in your mac
3. Now open the terminal application
4. Run the following command => **npm install -g appium**
5. This should install Appium in your system with global privileges. After installation of appium, you can run the command => **appium-doctor** in the same terminal window to verify if everything is installed properly.
6. If everything is in green ticks, run => **appium &** to start the appium server

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers points out, if you have installed Appium thru terminal then simply type `appium &` on a terminal window to start appium server. Here all you need to know, how to install appium thru terminal.
1. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2. Give Following commands one by one to install [appium](http://appium.io/)

```
brew install node      # get node.js
npm install -g appium  # get appium
npm install wd         # get appium client
appium &               # start appium
```

You can find refer to step by guide for [appium download osx](http://www.testautomationsimplified.com/appium-tutorial/appium-download-osx/) here.

Answer (score 0):

```
String tellCommand = "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"/usr/bin/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js";
        String parameters = " -p "+port;
        parameters += " "+ (fullReset ? "--full-reset" : "--no-reset")+"\"";
        tellCommand += parameters;

        String[] command = { "osascript", "-e",
        tellCommand };

        ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        pBuilder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to launch your appium server programmatically for mac os, it includes automating the webkit debug proxy as well which is needed for debugging.

```
    //customize the below in start server method
//Webkit Proxy command

CommandLine iOSProxyCommand = new CommandLine("ios_webkit_debug_proxy");
iOSProxyCommand.addArgument("-c");
iOSProxyCommand.addArgument(udid+":27753");//provide your udid of the device
iOSProxyCommand.addArgument("-F");//to disable console output in eclipse

DefaultExecuteResultHandler iOSProxyresultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
DefaultExecutor iOSProxyexecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
iOSProxyexecutor.setExitValue(1);
try {
iOSProxyexecutor.execute(iOSProxyCommand, iOSProxyresultHandler);
iOSProxyCommand.toString()));
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("iOS Proxy started.");
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

CommandLine command = new CommandLine(
"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node");
command.addArgument( "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js",
false);
command.addArgument("--address", false);
command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");
command.addArgument("--port", false);
command.addArgument("4723");
command.addArgument("--full-reset", false);
command.addArgument("--log-level", false);//to disable console output in eclipse
command.addArgument("error");
command.addArgument("--log", false);
Timestamp currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
command.addArgument("/Users/sethupandi/appium"+currentTimestamp+".log");
DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setExitValue(1);
try {
executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("Appium server started.");
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

//customize the below in stop appium server-

//kill appium node after end of your execution
String[] command = { "/usr/bin/killall", "-9", "node" };
try {
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
System.out.println("Appium server stopped.");
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
//Kill webkit proxy for iOS
String[] commandProxy = { "/usr/bin/killall", "-9", "ios_webkit_debug_proxy" };
try {
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandProxy);
System.out.println("iOS Webkit proxy stopped");
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is a good way to launch 'appium' as a separate process. Another approach is to use the 'pm2' process manager, which is specifically designed to launch and manage Node processes.
BTW - I'll definitely add 'ios_webkit_debug_proxy' to my bag of tricks!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody reading this who happens to be using npm (node/js/typescript), I've created a module called [appium-controller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-controller) that starts and stops appium in the background programmatically (mac or windows). It has an option to pass in a specific port either through a node call to the method or through cli.